# Convert codec using Emgu CV

Tags: c#, emgucv, codec

I'm using Emgu CV to extract frame from video file in C#.

When I try to create a new `Capture` instance with file name, I get an error, probably because this file codec is unknown for Emgu CV.

How can I convert the codec of the file to codec which supported by Emgu CV programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Best answer:
Manually convert your source to a codec OpenCV understands using a converter like [this](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html)

Actual answer to your question:
Invoke the command line of a tool that does the converting for you like ffmpeg and wait for it to finish, then start loading the converted file...